# How can I combine multiple days' values into a month in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have many devices in various states (essentially "operating" or "down", but there are other statuses). A snapshot is taken at the end of each day to record what state a device is in. I am rolling up the COUNT of devices to an overall "operating" or "down" (e.g. 726 CCTVs are "operating" on 01-01-18 and 4 CCTVs are "down" on 01-01-18, 728 CCTVs are "operating" on 01-02-18 and 2 CCTVs are "down" on 01-02-18, etc.).

This is my current code:

```
SELECT oper.failurecode AS 'Device Type', 
       COUNT(hist.status) AS 'Count', 
       hist.status AS 'Status', 
       CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(MINUTE, -30, hist.datadatetime)) AS 'Date'
FROM locations loc
        INNER JOIN locoper oper ON oper.location = loc.location
        INNER JOIN serclochistory hist ON hist.location = loc.location
WHERE hist.status NOT IN ('DECOMMISSIONED', 'TRANSITION', 'NOT READY', 'NOT READY - Fiber') 
  AND CONVERT(TIME, hist.datadatetime) > '23:00:00'
GROUP BY 
    CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(MINUTE, -30, hist.datadatetime)), 
    oper.failurecode, 
    hist.status
ORDER BY 
    CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(MINUTE, -30, hist.datadatetime)), 
    oper.failurecode, 
    hist.status;
```

This gives me a result like below:

```
CCTV   6    DOWN       2018-01-01
CCTV   763  OPERATING  2018-01-01
CCTV   18   DOWN       2018-01-02
CCTV   748  OPERATING  2018-01-02
```

What I want to do is combine all of the devices for the month so I can see a result like below:

```
CCTV   24   DOWN       2018-01
CCTV   1511 OPERATING  2018-01
```

I can find examples of how to combine items to a single line, but not to add values in this manner.

Comment: What database are you using? Is this Oracle?

Comment: I'm connecting to a Microsoft SQL server database via DbVisualizer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd be tempted to go with a Common Table Expression (CTE) for the initial data capture.  This way you only need to convert the date values once.  It's also a bit easier to read your grouping and ordering.

I'm unclear as to the necessity of taking 30 minutes off the date value, but I think the intent is to capture status records 30-minutes either side of midnight.  Your query as posted doesn't do this because the time filter isn't on an adjusted value.

Anyway - give this a shot.  I hope it helps.

```
;WITH statusFilteredRecords ([Device Type], [Status], [Date])
-- Set of records filtered by status, with the time adjustment of -30 minutes applied to the date.
AS
(
    SELECT      oper.failurecode AS 'Device Type', 
                hist.status AS 'Status', 
                DateAdd(MINUTE, -30, hist.dateadatetime) [Date] -- This normalises "End of Day" as being midnight +/- 30 minutes
    FROM        locations loc
    INNER JOIN  locoper oper 
            ON  oper.location = loc.location
    INNER JOIN  serclochistory hist 
            ON  hist.location = loc.location
    WHERE       hist.status NOT IN ('DECOMMISSIONED', 'TRANSITION', 'NOT READY', 'NOT READY - Fiber')       
)
, eodFilteredRecords ([Device Type], [Status], [Date])
-- Set of records filtered by Time, so that only EOD records are included, with the date normalized to the first of the month for grouping
AS  
(
    SELECT  [Device Type],
            [Status],
            CAST(DateAdd(dd, -(day([Date])-1), [Date]) as Date) AS [Date] -- Force the date to the first of the month.
    FROM    statusFilteredRecords
    WHERE   CONVERT(TIME, [Date]) > '23:00:00' -- Because we're operating on the normalized datetime value, this is really > 23:30 or < 00:30
)
SELECT      [Device Type], 
            count([Status]) as [Count],
            [Status], 
            [Date]
FROM        eodFilteredRecords
GROUP BY    [Device Type], 
            [Status], 
            [Date]
ORDER BY    [Date], 
            [Device Type], 
            [Status]
```

**<== EDIT: Commentary to answer OP's request for an explanation ==>**

`Count()` is an aggregate function - it operates on the data within a subgroup of the results.
In this case, the subgroups are those that match on `[Device Type]`, `[Status]` and `[Date]` - this is specified in the `GROUP BY` clause of the query.

```
GROUP BY    [Device Type], 
            [Status], 
            [Date]
```

In the original query, the `GROUP BY` clause converted the `DateTime` values within the field `hist.dateadatetime` to `Date` values (with no time component).  Removing the *time* part of the value means that all values for a given *day* are now equal, and all form part of the same sub-group.  (`01-Jan-2018 15:22:33` becomes `01-Jan-2018`, as does `01-Jan-2018 22:51:00` etc).

```
GROUP BY 
    CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(MINUTE, -30, hist.datadatetime)), 
    oper.failurecode, 
    hist.status
```

What I have done is to take this one step further to effectively remove the *time* part and the *day* part of the value, setting all the dates to be the first of the month.

```
CAST(DateAdd(dd, -(day([Date])-1), [Date]) as Date) AS [Date]
```

Let's assume a date of 28th September, 2018.  I use `day([Date])` to get the day of the month (e.g. 28) and subtract 1 from this value (gives 27) and take that number of days off the date, so it falls back to the 1st day of the month.

So now when the we evaluate the `GROUP BY [Device Type], [Status], [Date]`, we group together all the records that occur within the same *month* (`11-Sep-2018` becomes `01-Sep-2018`, as does `30-Sep-2018`, etc).

Applying the aggregate function `Count()` to these less granular groups of records (grouped my month rather than day) gives the rolled-up result you are looking for.

Comment: I tried a direct copy and past, but the function DateFromParts is only available in Server 2012+ and I'm on 2008. I replaced it with dateadd(dd, 3 -1, dateadd(mm, datediff(mm,0, current_timestamp), 0)), which fixed the error, but I'm not sure was the right piece of code. After that there was an error that said eodRecords was an invalid object name, so I replaced it with the table that the timestamp was from, serclochistory. Now I'm getting an error that 'Date' and 'Device Type' are invalid column names. I tried to replace them with the proper names, but that threw a "could not be bound" error.

Comment: I forgot to add that yes, the -30 is to get either side of midnight. The Timestamp runs at 11:59 PM, so if it runs over, it will only get part of the records. That was the intent for the DateAdd. I'm still new at SQL, so perhaps that wasn't the best way to do it.

Comment: Apologies on the table names - I was writing without the benefit of your tables so my query didn't actually run :)  I have adjusted my answer for this and also replaced the DateFromParts function.

Comment: Alright, so no errors this time. However the result is kind of odd; I'm not sure what it's doing. See the following (sorry that I can't format it properly in a comment):

CCTV     2     Operating     2018-01-01 23:29:00
CCTV     1     Operating     2018-01-01 23:29:00
CCTV     2     Operating     2018-01-01 23:29:00

It just repeats that throughout the month, for each device, then repeats that for the following months. I think this may be on the right track. What I'm wanting to do is to roll up all of the month's counts into single count for each status. Does that make sense?

Comment: @TaRan, try changing `DateAdd(dd, -(day([Date])-1), [Date]) AS [Date]` to cast the result to a Date like this `cast(DateAdd(dd, -(day([Date])-1), [Date]) as Date) AS [Date]`.  This is something that I missed when I replaced the `DateFromParts`statement.  It could be that the records have some millisecond part that is throwing out the grouping.  If that doesn't work, please post some sample data and I'll pull that into my queries to resolve the issue.  If that cast works, I'll update my answer :)

Comment: Great! It looks like the CAST was what was missing. The query is pulling the proper data now. Thanks a lot for the help Brett. You're a life saver. If you have a moment, can you explain to me how this is rolling up the COUNTs into one group?

Comment: Brilliant - knew we'd get you there in the end.  I'll add some commentary to the answer to explain what we did here compared to your original script.

Answer (score 0):

Your query suggest `SQL Server` syntax if so, then you can do :

```
SELECT oper.failurecode AS 'Device Type', COUNT(hist.status) AS 'Count', hist.status AS 'Status', CONVERT(DATE, DATEADD(MINUTE, -30, hist.datadatetime)) AS 'Date'
FROM locations loc INNER JOIN 
     locoper oper 
     ON oper.location = loc.location INNER JOIN 
     serclochistory hist 
     ON hist.location = loc.location
WHERE hist.status NOT IN ('DECOMMISSIONED', 'TRANSITION', 'NOT READY', 'NOT READY - Fiber') AND CONVERT(TIME, hist.datadatetime) > '23:00:00'
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(7), DATEADD(MINUTE, -30, hist.datadatetime), 120), oper.failurecode, hist.status
ORDER BY Date, oper.failurecode, hist.status;
```

Comment: I tried a straight copy and paste of this into DBV, but that gave me an error saying that "serclochistory.datadatetime' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause." I added it to the GROUP BY clause, which fixed the error, but didn't change my result.